# nameSpace error in XPages

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

This morning the error happened. I have no idea why?

ERROR DETAILS: Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type
The unknown namespace tag bx:select2PickerCombo cannot be used as a control, as the namespace http://www.openntf.org/xsp/bootstrap is not known.    xspFrmSta.xsp   fileName.nsf/XPages line 680    XPages Problem

[image: Error Screenshot]

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build automatically has been disabled then whole project was cleaned up and built
now it works great.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure whichever extension library the bx prefix relates to is installed on that install of Domino Designer. If it's not, Designer won't be able to compile (to convert the XML in your XPage to the relevant Java classes).